# In Fedora, how do I turn off the automatic dictionary suggestions?

Tags: fedora, terminal, spell-checking, dictionary, ibus

I just installed Fedora 19 in VirtualBox using an image from [virtualboxes.org](http://virtualboxes.org/images/fedora/#fedora19).  It suggests words from a dictionary wherever I type.  It's slow and it won't let me type what I want, since it automatically inserts the topmost dictionary suggestion.

How do I turn it off?

[image: Terminal]

Comment: I've never seen this behavior, but there does appear to be a predictive spelling package **ibus-typing-booster** installed perhaps by default. My installation had no config for this, so it does nothing. Try removing it (there appear to be no dependent packages) and see if that fixes it. This is certainly a stab in the dark, though. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Typing-Booster

Answer (score 2):

[SuperMagic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14401/supermagic) provided the [correct answer in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104216/in-fedora-how-do-i-turn-off-the-automatic-dictionary-suggestions/104218#comment159543_104216):

> I've never seen this behavior, but there does appear to be a
>   predictive spelling package **ibus-typing-booster** installed perhaps by
>   default. My installation had no config for this, so it does nothing.
>   Try removing it (there appear to be no dependent packages) and see if
>   that fixes it. This is certainly a stab in the dark, though.
>   [fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Typing-Booster](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Typing-Booster)

So I did a `yum remove ibus-typing-booster` and killed the ibus-typing-booster process.  Voila!